# Debugar javascript Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, debug

preciso de uma ajuda por favor.

Seguinte eu tinha uma máquina com Win 7 32bits e conseguia debugar o javascript normal no Visual Studio 2013, colocava o breakpoint e ele parava belezinha.

Daí troquei para o Win 8 64 bits e agora não consigo mais, pois não para no breakpoint.

Quando instalei o VS2013 na nova máquina, importei as configurações da máquina antiga e veio tudo certinho. Até comparei em TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> Debuging e está tudo igual.

Detalhe que quando instalei o VS2013 na máquina anterior, não precisei configurar nada.
Vi em outro fórum que o update 2 do VS2013 resolvia, instalei o update 3 mas continua na mesma.

Outra coisa é que já desmarquei a opção de desabilita o depurador no IE 11.

Se alguém tiver uma ideia, agradeço.

Comment: Você instalou o update 2? ou somente o 3?

Comment: Tem sempre o debugger do navegador também. Em quase todos eles você o abre com F12.

Answer (score 1):

Você também consegue depurar javascript no VS 2013 incluindo o termo "debugger" na linha do javascript que deseja que o depuração pare.

```
debugger;
```